# Problem migrating to a newer nativescript

Tags: android, exception, nativescript

I am currently updating my mobile app project from nativescript 5.2.1 to version 6. however trying to run it will always trigger this problem, and i am not sure how to handle it

when i check the code, it seemed it tried to split global.process.version or process.version either in vendor.js or pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
File: (file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142790:54)

StackTrace: 
../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142790:55)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/sync.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142852:23)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/index.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142658:24)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:58549:9)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ./global/functions.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:22025:64)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ./global/init.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:22311:68)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at (file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:20643:70)
    at ./app.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:20701:30)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at checkDeferredModules(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:44:23)
    at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:31:19)
    at (file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
    at require(:1:266)


TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

StackTrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
File: (file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142790:54)

StackTrace: 
../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142790:55)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/sync.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142852:23)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/index.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142658:24)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:58549:9)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ./global/functions.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:22025:64)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ./global/init.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:22311:68)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at (file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:20643:70)
    at ./app.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:20701:30)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at checkDeferredModules(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:44:23)
    at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:31:19)
    at (file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
    at require(:1:266)


TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6318)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1867)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:956)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
File: (file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142790:54)

StackTrace: 
../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142790:55)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/sync.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142852:23)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/index.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:142658:24)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ../node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/vendor.js:58549:9)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ./global/functions.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:22025:64)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ./global/init.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:22311:68)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at (file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:20643:70)
    at ./app.js(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:20701:30)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:751:30)
    at checkDeferredModules(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:44:23)
    at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/runtime.js:31:19)
    at (file:///data/data/com.ikredo.ikredolenderapp/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
    at require(:1:266)


TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:674)
    at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:666)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6313)
    ... 8 more
```

trying to get over the "please add some more details", sorry to look unprofessional but i cannot describe any more detail

Edit:
as requested here is my package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.xxxx",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "Lender",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nativescript-background-http": "^3.4.0",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
    "nativescript-cardview": "^3.1.1",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^4.1.0",
    "nativescript-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^1.2.0",
    "nativescript-datetimepicker": "^1.0.2",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^5.0.0",
    "nativescript-fingerprint-auth": "^6.2.0",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^6.1.2",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.4.0",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "^2.4.0",
    "nativescript-lottie": "^3.0.2",
    "nativescript-material-bottomsheet": "^2.2.5",
    "nativescript-material-ripple": "^2.2.5",
    "nativescript-material-textfield": "^2.2.3",
    "nativescript-pager": "^9.4.0",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^2.0.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "9.0.2",
    "nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^2.3.0",
    "nativescript-sqlite": "^2.3.3",
    "nativescript-statusbar": "^5.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-vue": "2.3.0",
    "nativescript-web-image-cache": "^5.0.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "6.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "~8.0.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.0.1",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "2.3.0",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "vue-loader": "~15.4.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "6.0.1"
  },
  "gitHead": "xxx",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "maxLogcatObjectSize": 1000000
}
```

Comment: Can you update the post with your content in `package.json`?

Comment: i have added it

Comment: I think we need more details, Is there any specific reason you are sticking with 6.0 and not the latest which I guess 6.3 as of today. Also most of your dev dependencies are somewhat outdated, like nativescript webpack, vue template compiler etc., Did you try updating them too? You have to make sure one is compatible with another, from CLI to runtime, core modules, webpack etc., Did you update the versions manually Or via CLI?

Comment: Have you solved this? I am facing same problem when trying to implement image upload with nativescript-background-http

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, "something" is attempting to perform a `split` on a string that either doesn't exist or has not been initialized. Off the top of my head, I can't say, "I've run into this exact thing and here is the solution." However, I've definitely run into some...interesting...issues when updating my project dependencies. My first guess is that your `webpack.config.js` needs to be updated to match the new dependencies. But that isn't much more than a gut feeling or a place to start.

With that, here are some things which may [or may not] be helpful. Anytime I update my dependencies now, I run through these triage points:

- Run `tns doctor` and see if it has any opinions about any existing dependencies
- As of NativeScript 6.3.0, there is no longer a need to use the older `tns-core-modules/`. Instead, use `@nativescript/core/`. If you are using the older, backward-compatible modules, make sure that their versions have also been updated (both `tns-core-modules` and `tns-platform-declarations`).
- When I updated my dependencies, I also deleted my `webpack.config.js` file so that NativeScript would generate a new, current version. `tns update` does not appear to update the Webpack config. At most, a warning may go by in the hundreds of lines of console output while building. After I deleted my Webpack config, and thus allowing NativeScript to generate a new one, GitHub showed some significant differences between the old/new versions.
- Thoroughly clean your project: Empty or delete the `node_modules` folder and run `tns platform clean android` and `tns platform clean ios`.

Hopefully, some part of this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `var process = require('process');` at the top of the `default-encoding.js` and `_stream_writable.js` fixed it for me.